# How can you stop your phone from saving contacts to your sim?

Tags: contacts, sim-card, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

I Have a T-Mobile Sidekick 4G. It runs on Gingerbread. I just got my phone and when I first tried to enter a contact I accidentally pressed "Save to Sim" and "Remember This Choice". I really want to save contacts to my phone but it won't let me. How do I un-do this? This is really annoying!

Comment: You can undo this from Settings of Contacts app..

Answer (score 6):

Open Contacts then press the menu button go to More>Settings in that the first option is where you want to save your contacts .

Comment: The answer above does not work .... I don't see a More>Settings option....